# Sticky header wont update according to my changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a number of checkboxes that are created with Angular. Each checkbox controls the appearance of a column on a table. So if I click checkbox number 3, then column number 3 of the table will not be visible anymore.

I achieve this by simply doing

```
$('#dynamic tr > *:nth-child('+idx+')').toggle();
```

I stumbled upon this [article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/09/sticky-table-headers-columns/) though, and I wanted to use it in my table.

The thing is that the sticky header that is created from the javascript file, will not follow my actual table. So it will insist in displaying column 2 when it should have been deleted.

I thought that if I run this each time I hide or show a column then it will update correctly, but if you do so, even though the header does indeed update, for some reason a lot of empty space started appearing after each click. And by clicking  more than a few times the page would slow down.

Since the code for the sticky header is generated on the fly from the javascript code I tried hiding and showing the appropriate items in the same way I am doing it with my actual table.

```
$('.sticky-thead th > *:nth-child('+idx+')').toggle();
```

This has no effect whatsoever though.
Can someone figure out a better way to make the sticky header dynamic, so it displays only those items that are visible in my table at every moment?

**EDIT**

The javascript file I am mentioning contains the following code that is used to generate a sort of a sticky header.

```
$(function(){
    $('table').each(function() {
        if($(this).find('thead').length > 0 && $(this).find('th').length > 0) {
            var $w     = $(window),
                $t     = $(this),
                $thead = $t.find('thead').clone(),
                $col   = $t.find('thead, tbody').clone();

            $t
            .addClass('sticky-enabled')
            .css({
                margin: 0,
                width: '100%'
            }).wrap('<div class="sticky-wrap" />');

            if($t.hasClass('overflow-y')) $t.removeClass('overflow-y').parent().addClass('overflow-y');

            $t.after('<table class="sticky-thead" />');

            if($t.find('tbody th').length > 0) {
                $t.after('<table class="sticky-col" /><table class="sticky-intersect" />');
            }

            var $stickyHead  = $(this).siblings('.sticky-thead'),
                $stickyCol   = $(this).siblings('.sticky-col'),
                $stickyInsct = $(this).siblings('.sticky-intersect'),
                $stickyWrap  = $(this).parent('.sticky-wrap');

            $stickyHead.append($thead);

            $stickyCol
            .append($col)
                .find('thead th:gt(0)').remove()
                .end()
                .find('tbody td').remove();

            $stickyInsct.html('<thead><tr><th>'+$t.find('thead th:first-child').html()+'</th></tr></thead>');

            var setWidths = function () {
                    $t
                    .find('thead th').each(function (i) {
                        $stickyHead.find('th').eq(i).width($(this).width());
                    })
                    .end()
                    .find('tr').each(function (i) {
                        $stickyCol.find('tr').eq(i).height($(this).height());
                    });

                    $stickyHead.width($t.width());

                    $stickyCol.find('th').add($stickyInsct.find('th')).width($t.find('thead th').width())
                },
                repositionStickyHead = function () {
                    var allowance = calcAllowance();

                    if($t.height() > $stickyWrap.height()) {
                        if($stickyWrap.scrollTop() > 0) {
                            $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                                opacity: 1,
                                top: $stickyWrap.scrollTop()
                            });
                        } else {
                            $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                                opacity: 0,
                                top: 0
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        if($w.scrollTop() > $t.offset().top && $w.scrollTop() < $t.offset().top + $t.outerHeight() - allowance) {
                            $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                                opacity: 1,
                                top: $w.scrollTop() - $t.offset().top
                            });
                        } else {
                            $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                                opacity: 0,
                                top: 0
                            });
                        }
                    }
                },
                repositionStickyCol = function () {
                    if($stickyWrap.scrollLeft() > 0) {
                        $stickyCol.add($stickyInsct).css({
                            opacity: 1,
                            left: $stickyWrap.scrollLeft()
                        });
                    } else {
                        $stickyCol
                        .css({ opacity: 0 })
                        .add($stickyInsct).css({ left: 0 });
                    }
                },
                calcAllowance = function () {
                    var a = 0;
                    $t.find('tbody tr:lt(3)').each(function () {
                        a += $(this).height();
                    });

                    if(a > $w.height()*0.25) {
                        a = $w.height()*0.25;
                    }

                    // Add the height of sticky header
                    a += $stickyHead.height();
                    return a;
                };

            setWidths();

            $t.parent('.sticky-wrap').scroll($.throttle(250, function() {
                repositionStickyHead();
                repositionStickyCol();
            }));

            $w
            .load(setWidths)
            .resize($.debounce(250, function () {
                setWidths();
                repositionStickyHead();
                repositionStickyCol();
            }))
            .scroll($.throttle(250, repositionStickyHead));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The code you're asking about really should be directly included in your question here.

Comment: do you have access to change the code and give it a name?

Comment: I am not directly including it because it was not written by me. But I suppose you are correct.

Comment: I'm not clear where the function is but just copy the function out, give it a name, and put the name back where the function came from. Post the code and i'll show you how, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting the table via id (`#`). Every id should be unique for each element on the page. If the scripts clones the table, it will not work. Try using a class attribute instead.

Comment: I did try that but there where no visible changes to the header.